# How to add Quartz JobListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I am writing a java/spring library to include in other projects that are using quartz. I need it to log something before each task is executed.

I have a simple JobListener that looks like this:

```
public class MyJobListener extends JobListenerSupport {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(LoggingJobListener.class);

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MyJobListener";
    }

    @Override
    public void jobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {
        log.info("job will start")   
    }
}
```

I know we can do something like this to add joblisteners:

```
scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(myJobListener, allJobs());
```

But how can I get the scheduler to add so I can add the listener?

I have tried implementing the `SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer` but can't figure out how to add the listener (since the scheduler is not created yet?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Postconstruct and add JobListener there.

```
@Component
public class JobListenerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void addListeners() throws SchedulerException {

        schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler()
                            .getListenerManager()
                            .addJobListener(new MyJobListener());
    }
}
```